# How to prove $ABC$ is isoceles?

Tags: geometry

[image]

In Triangle $ABC$, $M$ lies on $AC$ and $N$ lies on $AB$ such that $\angle BNC = 4x$, $\angle CMB = 5x$,$\angle CBM =5x$ and $\angle NCB =6x$.
Prove that triangle $ABC$ is isosceles.

My attempt: [image]

Can someone please help me? I really am stuck.

Comment: Hint: Your above drawing shows that the angles $\angle BCA$ and $\angle CBA$ are equal

Comment: You have virtually proved it: Work out what angle C and angle B are in terms of $x$

Comment: Thank you @Mufasa. Is there a way to work out the numerical value of $x$ or not?

Comment: I believe that there are an infinite number of solutions for $x$

Answer (score 0):

Since the triangle is isosceles, we know that both angles $B$ and $C$ must be less than $90^{\circ}$. Therefore, if you look at angle $C$ then we can state that:$$180-16x+6x\lt90$$$$\therefore x\gt9^{\circ}$$And looking at angle A we can state that:$$20x-180\lt180$$$$\therefore x\lt18^{\circ}$$So I believe $x$ is bounded by:$$9^{\circ}\lt x\lt18^{\circ}$$